# Virtual Desktop Manager for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtual-desktop

I'm surprised to still *NOT* see a build in feature to be able to utilized more then one desktop!

I mean *every* popular OS has it build in! Apple Mac OS X, Linux, Solaris and I'm pretty sure many others...

that's really sad!

any suggestions what would be a good suggestion for that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few third party applications that have all the advanced graphic rich features of other operating systems, but if you just want a working, light-weight solution, I recommend [Microsoft / Sysinternals Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx)

[image]

Comment: SysInternals Desktops has some severe problems: Keyboard shortcuts do not seem to work on the secondary desktops. And applications like Firefox cannot be opened in more than one virtual desktop.

Comment: that's not the most severe pain with sysinternals' component. you have no ability to move apps across desktops, which kinda defeats the whole emergent task self-organization idea. you have to plan what apps run where before you start'em.

Answer (score 25):

**[Dexpot](http://www.dexpot.de/index.php?lang=en)** allows you to create multiple, virtual desktops to increase the work area of your screen by **up to 20** times. Each virtual desktop is independent from the others and can have its individual wallpaper, resolution, and icons (or no icons at all). You can easily switch between desktops from the tray icon, or via hotkey, or even use an automatic desktop slideshow that rotates all virtual desktops. In addition, you can move and copy windows from one desktop to another among the desktops, set up rules to automatically move, copy or close windows and more. Dexpot is one of the most advanced desktop managers out there, that is easy enough for beginners, but offers some great flexibility for more demanding users as well.

[image]

[image]

Despite its sophistication, Dexpot is using only 2 MB RAM.

*Dexpot is freeware, suitable for Windows 2000/XP/2003/Vista/2008/7 (incl. x64) portable versions are available too.*

Comment: I LOVE Dexpot. Don't forget some of the Windows7 enhancements for switching desktops, plus the hotkeys to rollup windows and minimize to tray.

Comment: MAN. This is nice.

Comment: this might be cool but I am required to purchase a license if I am an employee or freelancer, thus I did not install it as I don't need this app that often (I mainly use Linux)

Comment: Note this is reported to install Adware

Comment: has some issues since last windows 10 upgrade. start menue and cortana dont work properly on all virtual desktops but the first.

Answer (score 11):

The popular [VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/) is a free and open source virtual desktop manager for Windows. It advertises support for Windows 9x/ME/NT/2000/XP/Server 2003/Vista, although I assume that part of the site hasn't been updated as it works [fine on Windows 7](http://www.syschat.com/virtuawin-access-multiple-virtual-desktops-windows-5036.html).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[mDesktop](http://code.google.com/p/mdesktop) is free and simple:

*mDesktop is a lightweight application that allows the user to utilize multiple virtual desktops. mDesktop currently supports up to ten virtual desktops.*

Comment: FYI some versions install OpenCandy

Answer (score 2):

[WindowsPager](http://www.windows7.cc/windows-7-software/windows-7-virtual-desktop-manager/) looks like it is worth to try.