# Multiple Workspaces in Windows with Two Monitors

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop

I have a dual monitor (soon to be a three-monitor) setup. I am running windows 7 and my machine is capable of anything (no worries about memory hogs or intensive cpu loads).

What I would like to do is have virtual desktops / workspaces like you find in linux/solaris/mac. I have considered [360Desktop](http://www.360desktop.com/) because I thought that would allow me to make better use of multiple monitors without any hacking. However, I wanted to know what else is out there.

One feature that would be great is to have one monitor as a home (never changing) and the other monitor to have multiple spaces. But I could still drag from home to any currently used workspace and vice-versus. It might also be cool if each monitor could have multiple workspaces.

**GIGANTIC EDIT:** I am in college and would prefer not to spend money on something like this, so please suggest something open-source

Comment: Why is it that you can afford 3 monitors but not $20 worth of software?  I'll never understand that mentality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update

We posted a couple of freebies earlier today in this thread:

**[Virtual Desktop Manager for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/98075/virtual-desktop-manager-for-windows-7/98222#98222)**

however, i can only recommend this baby for any multi-monitor environment:

> **[Actual Window Manager](http://www.actualtools.com/windowmanager/)** is an innovative desktop organization
>   application which introduces
>   unconventional window controls and
>   also automatic general window
>   operations making your work more
>   productive, convenient and enjoyable.
>   It has more than 50 handy tools to
>   help you in daily routine window
>   manipulations.

... it's got it all (including virtual desktops, expandable Taskbar with Start Button/Orb on each monitor)

*Actual Window Manager is shareware, try before you buy.*

If you're looking for a Window Manager, there is a free alternative alternative, not bad, but it can't hold a candle Actual Window Manager:

Eusing's **[Auto Window Manager](http://www.eusing.com/WindowManager/WindowManager.htm)**

Comment: @macneil - updated my post accordingly, however, you may try AWM and enjoy their 60-days evaluation period, there is simply no better program. :)

Comment: Hey I really like dexpot. It is working well and is surprisingly low resource. I like the hotkey feature and it works well with two monitors. The only con is that some times windows will begin to load in one workspace and if you switch workplaces it will finish opening in the new workspace.

Comment: +1 on Dexpot. I've been using it for a long time now and it is great, especially with the additional features, like window rollups and the like. Whoops, better go upvote the other thread.