# Which virtual desktop works properly?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virtual Desktop Manager for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/98075/virtual-desktop-manager-for-windows-7)
>   [Virtual desktop(alt+ctrl+1,2,3,4,…) like linux on windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/65430/virtual-desktopaltctrl1-2-3-4-like-linux-on-windows-7)

Hello

i have tried few virtual desktop software but all had some annoying sides.Deskspace was nice and good but it is not freeware also it doesnt work properly always . Other one was Dexpot which has many functionality and nice 3d effects but it is also doesn't work properly.I am waiting suggestions.

By the way i tried them on windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: duplicate of [Virtual Desktop Manager for Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/98075/virtual-desktop-manager-for-windows-7).