# Several desktops on Windows?

Tags: windows, software-rec, virtual-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virtual Desktop Manager for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/98075/virtual-desktop-manager-for-windows-7)

Windows XP, Windows 7, what is the best program to have several workspaces just like under Linux/GNOME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somedays ago, my workmate told me these 2 virtual desktop tools, both are great. But since "which is best" is subjective, you can try them each to pick your favorite.

- [dexpot](http://www.dexpot.de)
- [Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881) (an utility of [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com) [Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062))

**Note:**

dexpot does not create new `explorer.exe` process when create virtual desktops. Desktops will create new `explorer.exe` process for each virtual desktop.