# Dexpot carries malware?

Tags: malware, virtual-desktop, malware-removal

Dexpot appears to have a lion market share as far as virtual desktop managers go. It also seems to have a rep for adware/bloatware or worse; at least the dexpot.de site does:

https://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/dexpot.de/comment-68802081#comment-68802081
http://www.calendarofupdates.com/updates/index.php?showtopic=16109&p=105170
http://download.cnet.com/Dexpot/9241-2346_4-13143779.html?messageID=10922154

Some of the bloatware listed is Conduit, MyFreeGames, OpenCandy

I've been trying to figure out whether Dexpot is safe to install; but since someone said it's is an opinion-based question, I'll be more specific:

1. Is Dexpot shipped with malware?
2. What is the malware's payload? Would it do something as malicious as install a keylogger or steal a credit card?
3. Can the malware be removed?

> phearce 09/16/2013 Malware or viruses Potentially unwanted programs
>   The Desktop Clock software came "bundled" with the
>   nearly-impossible-to-remove Conduit and MyFreeGames- toolbar malware.
>
> Very disappointing: the wallpaper clock is such a well executed idea. 
>   "

.

> "All benefits are undone by coupling with malware" September 23, 2013 
>   |    By justajiggolo
>   The version I downloaded (vie dexpot's own site, dexpot.de) came bundled with conduit "Search hijacker" - > giant PITA to remove, and you have to remove it from ALL browsers that you use.

Comment: VTC as "opinion-based" as it's hard for us to judge what's "bad" for you, or "how safe" something is.  As to the side question there is this duplicate question: [Virtual Desktop Manager for Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/98075/virtual-desktop-manager-for-windows-7?rq=1)

Comment: I don't see how it's a duplicate when it does not even attempt to answer my question. Also, what is VTC? I'll rephrase the question to be less opinion-based.

Comment: Well since before you edited it out your 'side-question', the last half of your question was "If not Dexpot, what are alternatives?" - that's what I was referencing as the duplicate.

Comment: Edited. Is my question OK now?

Comment: IMHO, a short side question does not a duplicate make. Besides, none of the software listed counts as alternatives according to my stated criteria. Side question removed.

Comment: VTC = Voting To Close.  As-is now, it's better, but I'd still say you're laking a bit of research.  IE: If you want to know what those malware do, look them up.  If you want to know if Dexpot includes them, download and install Dexpot (in a VM or sandbox), then do a malware scan.  Anyhow, takes more than just my vote to close it. :)

Comment: I didn't VTC this as a duplicate, I merely pointed it out to you to answer your side-question.  You know, trying to help you and all. :)

Comment: You've got to be kidding. I've spent about a week researching the subject, have read pretty much all SU had to say on it in the few past years (including the post you named as duplicate), and, as I had originally stated, have tried a number of these alternatives that seemed promising.

Comment: Installing a malware suspect in a VM or a sandbox I think is a terrible idea, because VMs leak these days. Please research the subject.

Comment: Also, as I am sure you know, no malware scan finds all malware. The absence of proof is not a proof of absence.

Comment: Nevertheless, you have a point: you did not VC for duplicate, just offered a link and then VCd for opinion-based. Thank you for the link ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You are correct to assume that no malware scan finds all malware... but there ARE sites that multi-test programs.

http://dexpot.en.lo4d.com/virus-malware-tests has tested Dexpot May5 2014 (2 days ago as of this post) and found it is clean from 27 different tests.

Comment: Nice link, thank you! Its rating does not seem very high. Wonder whether there are more popular sites that do the same?

Comment: I assume there are, I merely posted the first I found. I hope this is an adequate answer and puts you on the right path. Enjoy.

Comment: Hmm.. if they are so safe, why such horrible reviews?

Comment: The bad reviews I saw were 2 years old. If you're not interested in a poorly reviewed but clean product, this question is moot.

Comment: I suppose there is a possibility they've cleaned up. Although, I've seen clean products and sites going unclean, but this would be the first time I saw this happen the other way around. Does not seem like a valid business model, to take a bad rep product and build up its rep.

Comment: if the bad reviews you saw were 2 years old, that means you have not followed the links I provided, two of which were from Sept. 2013. Posted the quotes in my question for your convenience.

Comment: Given that Dexpot still ships with OpenCandy, which triggers many malware tools, I wonder why no malware tool had complained on the website you provided. To play the devil's advocate, what prevents a website from being run by a party with a conflict of interest? Given its low ranking, everything is possible. Will you trust an obscure website over a bunch of users?

Comment: My avast just flagged this with adware. FileRepMetagen.

Answer (score 2):

Deskpot may be all kinds of things, but "clean" is not one of them.

I just posted a question on adware on Deskpot forum:

http://dexpot.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=5534&p=35736#p35736

To summarize:

Yes, they still install adware, or programs that claim to do something useful but silently install adware. They claim you can opt-out. They've claimed it before, but users had a different experience, as seen from the links in my Q. Maybe you can opt-out for real now, I don't know.

They said they stopped installing Conduit products and all toolbars. They won't provide the list of programs they do install (I'll update this answer if this changes). They do still install TuneUp Utilities 2014, which has bad rep on CNet and, according to wikipedia, silently installs adware. (Wikipedia does not say whether it uninstalls cleanly, including the adware; in the past, that was not the case with Dexpot's third pa>rty bundles, but this may have changed). They do allow you to opt-out of TuneUp, or so they say.

It's a good thing Dexpot maintains a forum and answers questions instantly if/when they choose to, but one difficult question (such as "do your programs ever call home?"), and they stop answering - this has been my impression from looking at the forums.

I'll stay away from Dexpot and stick to VirtuaWin until I can see if someone can get them to do a public statement about what the software does NOT do. (Think about it this way: would not a legit company be eager to make such a statement?)

Comment: My virus scan (Symantec) also just flagged it as untrustworthy and automatically deleted it after I downloaded it.